# How to Connect Google Data Studio with Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, connection, looker-studio

I searched a lot on Internet, I think, not much or no one worked on Google Data Studio on scripting level. API's are available but I don't know how can I connect my Data Studio project with script to run any stuff using scripting.

To connect script with other Google Apps we write scripts which communicate with the following API's:

```
var GoogleSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Googleform = FormApp.openById('SOME-ID');
etc.
```

But to connect with Data Studio there is something different which not defines from which data studio project we are connecting:

```
var GoogleDataStudio = DataStudioApp().createCommunityConnector();
```

It Maybe be simple, but there is no straight source available to define its simplicity of connecting Data Studio with Google Script.

I want to connect my data studio specific schema with script to work on fields to automate filtering etc.

Please help me at that place. I will be huge Thankful to you.

Comment: Check out [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#0). Did you follow the steps specified there? If that's the case, where are you encountering problems?

Comment: I want to get fields of already connected Data Source. I found the way of creating new fields using script but I want something different. For example I have google sheet which is connected to data studio and data source is generated. Google Sheet have field with the name of "Credentials-Id", now I want to apply auto filter on it using script within Data Studio Report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataStudioApp` in Apps Script works as a helper library for creating Community Connectors for Data Studio. It is currently not possible to use Apps Script to interact with Data Studio the same way one would interact with Sheets or Docs. You cannot use Apps Script to manipulate Data Studio reports or data sources.