# Can Google script get a value from Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have a script in a Google sheet that searches the Google drive for files containing the search term as specified in a specific cell. Is it possible for that script to pick up the search term value from an Input Box added as Control in a Google Data Studio report, instead?

This is the code I have so far, which is working fine.

```
function SearchDrive2() {
   // declare this sheet and tab
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  //clear sheet
  sh1.getRange("A:F").clear();

  // set variables
  var searchterm = sh1.getRange("H1").getValue();
  var searchFor = 'fullText contains "'+searchterm+'"';
  var data = [];
  var names =[];
  var fileURLs = [];
  var fileDates = [];
  var fileTypes = [];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);

  // append a header row
  sh1.appendRow(["Name", "Date Last Updated", "URL", "Type", "File Type", "Helper Column",]);

  //run the search
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileurl = file.getUrl();
    var filedate = file.getLastUpdated();
    var filetype = file.getMimeType();

    names.push(file.getName());
    fileURLs.push(fileurl);
    fileDates.push(filedate);
    fileTypes.push(filetype);

    //create the results array
    data = [ 
      file,
      filedate,
      fileurl,
      filetype,
    ];

    //add results in the sheet
    sh1.appendRow(data);}
```

What I am looking for is how to replace the

```
var searchterm = sh1.getRange("H1").getValue();
```

with something that will get the search term from a data studio report input box.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: This might answer your question. [How to Connect Google Data Studio with Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59847757/14606046)

Comment: @Rubén I have edited the question and added the script I am using. I haven't tried something so far, as I have no idea what to try.

Comment: @RonM So, your suggestion is to try using the DataStudioApp class to create a CommunityConnector? Isn't this supposed to manipulate the data studio report?

Comment: No, what I meant was it is not possible to access your input box control in your data studio report using apps script. Hence you cannot use that to get your search term value

Comment: @RonM I see... how disappointing... :(

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using Data Studio Community Connectors.

1. Create a [community connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) that will use the search term as a config parameter. Your `getdata` function should make use of the code snippet you posted.
2. When creating a data source using the connector in Data Studio, make the parameter overridable. This will expose the parameter to the report.
3. In your report, use a text input control and tie it to the config parameter.